# MySQL query to set wp_postmeta using term_taxonomy_id value

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, mysql

I have a need to set the `wp_postmeta` value (in table: `wp_postmeta`)  on every post that has a specific `term_taxonomy_id` (in table: `wp_term_relationships`):

Specifically:

- run a query against every `post_ID` that has `term_taxonomy_id` value of 18
- if the `wp_postmeta` for that `post_ID` doesn't contain the key of `_category_permalink_` then add it with the value set to 18, otherwise ignore it

My MySQL foo is poor, so apologies if this makes no sense or I have got tables, names around the wrong way.

**UPDATE:**
In relation to answers/comments below by @deadlyhifi and @Jot I have the following:

```
function cleanup_permalink() {
    static $fnCount = 0; //to run only once
    if ($fnCount) return;
    $fnCount++;
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `object_id` FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = 18");
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        add_post_meta( $result, '_category_permalink_', '18', true);
    }
}
add_action('init','cleanup_permalink'); //i'm assuming init is the best place?
```

Comment: Are you running WP version 3.0 or greater?

Comment: did you figure this out yet?

Comment: Using latest version of WP (always update). And no, not figured out yet.

Comment: Run the code above - no luck. Function was included in theme `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what you mean, and if that is the case it's actually a straightforward operation.

Firstly [get all the](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) `object_id`s from the `term_relationship` table.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `object_id` FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = 18");
```

And then run through each of those values and [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to 18.

```
foreach ( $results as $result )
    update_post_meta($result, '_category_permalink_', '18', true);
```

It couldn't be that simple could it?

Comment: Probably you should use `add_post_meta( $result, '_category_permalink_', '18', true);`. This ensures that only posts without the key `_category_permalink_` will be changed. `update_post_meta()` will overwrite all existing keys, too.

Comment: Better append it as EDIT: to the original question.

Comment: edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks very much - I had made a mistake in the original question by adding a trailing underscore to the value - once I found that and fixed in PHPMyAdmin, everything was groovy.

Answer (score 2):

@deadlyhifi's answer looks good. I would suggest trying out `WP_Query` though for a more human readable "select" statement, suppose your term taxonomy 18 is the `foo` category, here's the equivalent with `WP_Query`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'foo', // slug, not name!
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_category_permalink_', 18, true );
}
```

You can also use `'cat' => 18` if you need to stick to the IDs. It's definitely not faster than the direct SQL method mentioned by @deadlyhifi, but it's friendlier to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT `object_id` FROM '.$wpdb->term_relationships.' WHERE  `term_taxonomy_id`=18';
$obj_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );
foreach( $obj_ids as $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_category_permalink_', '18' );
}
```

Should about do it for you, assuming @kovshenin's method does not work, since it's the better method for sure if it does (though I might try a foreach instead of the while personally, either is valid).

I have not directly tested this, but I've tested the query as well as checked the output on `$obj_ids`, so if it's not perfect, it's close.